# Should messages reside in the controller or model for a web site/web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, web-applications

In Django, there's the existence of a message framework which notifies the user after an action is performed.  For instance, from the `views.py` there might something like:

```
if success:
    messages.success(request, 'Update Successful')
else:
    messages.warning(request, 'Something is missing')
```

I believe Rails have something similar with:

```
flash[:notice] = 'Something is missing'
```

Should the messages above be hard-coded in the controller?

Comment: "hard-coded"? What's the alternative?  I18N translation of the message?  Or do you have something else in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are asking whether or not you should hard-code a string value into your code. In compiled languages, you often use a reference to a string, instead of entering the actual string. ala:

```
message.success(request, message_resource.success )
```

This gives you the freedom to change the string value without re-compiling the code, and has a performance benefit in some instances.

Because **Python** is dynamic this really isn't required, but depending on the size of the project, may be beneficial.

Imagine a situation where the software is used by people speaking different languages, you could detect the required language somewhere else in your code and initialize `message_resource.success`, as well as any other strings, to be in said language.

here is a simple example:

german.py

```
# german language messages
success = "Sie folgten!"
failure = "Sie fallen aus!"
```

english.py

```
#english language messages
success = "You succeeded!"
failure = "You fail!"
```

main.py

```
# main

# import english language
message_resource = __import__('english');

print message_resource.success
print message_resource.failure

# import german language
message_resource = __import__('german');

print message_resource.success
print message_resource.failure
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails any marshallable object can be put in the flash.
Therefore it is better to do it in the view.

```
<% if flash[:notices] && flash[:notices][:missing] %>
<div><%= t("Somethign missing") %></div>
<% end %>
```

Putting text and translations in the controllers is indeed a bit ugly..

Comment: Isn't this un-DRY -- if there were say, a Mobile browser view or XML or something else then the same text would need to be repeated in each view?

Comment: Delegate this to a partial then to remain DRY.. I doubt you'll render these kind of notices in XML anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Messages are events.  Things that happen.  Which is what the "controller" part of MVC is all about.  The "how".

(Django calls this "view functions".)

The model is (mostly) stuff that's static, final, persistent.  Passive.  The "what".

Things happen to the model.  Things are initiated by the controller.

Messages come from the controller for presentation to the person.

It's possible that a model's method might need to provide some evidence or information on a state change.  This is not an example of a message being created by the model.  If the model has methods that do mutation/update/state change, then you have to break things into two pieces.

The "controller" (i.e., Django view function) must use the model's API to make the state change and collect any information on that state change.

The "controller" (the view function) does I18N translation and presents the message.

Answer (score 1):

*generic examples*

- Model: The method `is_missing()` would go in the model, if it is dependent only on the data.
- Controller: Marshalling data from the model for the view: `missing = Suff.get_by_id(1).is_missing()`
- View: `<span>{$missing}<span>`

But exactly where you draw those lines is always up for debate. In your example, I would say `flash`, `success`, and `warning` are over-stepping their bounds on *how* to present the data and would be better in the view since they are generic data presenters.